# Calling certain comments from the data base

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I call comments + user information that is specified to the specific post the comment was created under. For example:

```
/articles/8

new comment created with user_id = 3

Page will show Username + comment + created_at
```

This is my current code:

*Post Show Page*

```
<%= @post.title %>
<%= render '/comments/form' %>    
<% @post.user.comments.reverse.each do |comment| %>
  <li>
    <%= comment.user.email %>
    <%= comment.comment %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I grab user information associated with the comment but the problem is, it's listing all the comments. How do I make only comments with article_id of 8 for example appear.

*Post Controller*

```
def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
 @post.user = current_user
 if @post.save!
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created..."
  redirect_to posts_path
 else
  flash[:danger] = "failed to add a post"
  render 'new'       
 end
end

def show
 @comment = Comment.new
 @comments = Comment.find(params[:id])
end
```

*Comment Controller*

```
def create
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
 @comment.user = current_user

 if @comment.save
  flash[:notice] = "Successfully created..."
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
 else
  flash[:alert] = "failed"
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end
```

*Routes*

```
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :users
resources :posts do
 resources :comments
end
```

*Schema of the comments*

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "comment"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: can you share the schema of the comments?

Comment: @MZaragoza Added my Schema.

Comment: and you want all the comments for post 8?

Comment: @MZaragoza Yes. I'm trying to correspond that only comments created within post 8 for example to show up. been trying to wrap my head around how to list all comments with post_id = 8 while also listing a user information.

Comment: let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your model looks like

```
class Comments < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end
```

We want to get all the comments for a post so we we can do something like this

```
# Note that I took the user from this line 
<% @post.comments.reverse.each do |comment| %>
  <li>
  <%= comment.user.email %>
  <%= comment.comment %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I hope that this should work.

Comment: works perfectly. Thank you. Just a question. How is user information still being accessed if we aren't calling the model? is it because it's part of the comment so we can access it?

Comment: a post have both users and comments. so you where looking at the wrong assignation